# Does $A^TA$ always result in a square matrix?

Tags: matrices, regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

And does the resulting $A^TA$ matrix always have an inverse to solve for $\vec{w}$ in

$$A^TA\vec{w}=A^T\vec{t}$$ ?

Comment: it is always a square, and always positive semidefinite. The rank is the same as that of $A,$ so if rank of $A$ is maximal ( the smaller dimension, columns or rows) it all works out

Comment: The right hand side of that equation should be $A^T \vec{t}$.

Comment: @littleO thanks fixed

Comment: The matrix is always square, but it need not be invertible. Easy counterexample: $A = 0$.

Comment: @TheoBendit  If $A^TA$ is not invertible then how do we solve for $\vec{w}$?

Comment: If $A^\top A$ is not invertible, then you still have a matrix equation that you can solve using Gauss-Jordan elimination. The resulting matrix equation should be consistent, but it will have infinitely many solutions. For many of the standard uses of normal equations (e.g. least squares), it suffices to choose a single solution for $\vec{w}$, but this may or not be appropriate for your purposes.

Comment: http://mlwiki.org/index.php/Normal_Equation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comments, $A^\top A$ is always square (Shogun covers this in more detail in their answer). However, $A^\top A$ may not have an inverse, particularly if the rank of $A$ does not match the number of columns of $A$, or equivalently, the columns are linearly dependent (which will always happen when $A$ has more columns than rows).

To answer the follow-up question in the comments (properly), you solve the matrix equation $A^\top A \vec{w} = A^\top \vec{t}$. This is done with Gauss-Jordan elimination.

Let's do an example to illustrate this. Take
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 2 & -1 & 3 \\ -1 & 1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}.$$
First, note that the second column plus the first column is the first column, and hence the columns are linearly dependent. I therefore expect $A^\top A%$ to be a rank two $3 \times 3$ matrix, which will make it singular. Computing,
$$A^\top A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 2 & -1 \\ 2 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 3 & -2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 2 & -1 & 3 \\ -1 & 1 & -2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 6 & -1 & 7 \\ -1 & 7 & -8 \\ 7 & -8 & 15 \end{pmatrix}.$$
This matrix is indeed singular, as (again, not coincidentally) the second and third columns add to give the first column (or compute the determinant).

We use this when taking a vector $\vec{t} \in \Bbb{R}^4$ and finding a vector $\vec{y}$ in the columnspace of $A$ that is closest (in the usual Euclidean $2$-norm) to $\vec{t}$. Let's take
$$\vec{t} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
We can see that $\vec{t}$ does not already belong to this columnspace by solving $A \vec{x} = \vec{t}$ and obtaining no solution. In this case, we would solve
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 2 & -1 & 3 \\ -1 & 1 & -2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},$$
which as an augmented matrix comes to
\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & 2 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & -1 & 3 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & -2 & 1 \end{array}\right) &\sim \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & 2 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -5 & 5 & -1 \\ 0 & 3 & -3 & 2 \end{array}\right) \\
&\sim \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & 2 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -6 \\ \color{red}0 & \color{red}0 & \color{red}0 & \color{red}5 \end{array}\right).
\end{align*}
The system is inconsistent, so indeed, $\vec{t}$ is not in the columnspace of $A$. However, we can multiply $A^\top$ to $\vec{t}$ to get
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 2 & -1 \\ 2 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 3 & -2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Our normal equation becomes
$$\begin{pmatrix} 6 & -1 & 7 \\ -1 & 7 & -8 \\ 7 & -8 & 15 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},$$
or as an augmented matrix,
\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 6 & -1 & 7 & 2 \\ -1 & 7 & -8 & 1 \\ 7 & -8 & 15 & 1 \end{array}\right) &\sim \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & -7 & 8 & -1 \\ 6 & -1 & 7 & 2 \\ 7 & -8 & 15 & 1 \end{array}\right) \\
&\sim \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & -7 & 8 & -1 \\ 0 & 41 & -41 & 8 \\ 0 & 41 & -41 & 8 \end{array}\right) \\
&\sim \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & -7 & 8 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & \frac{8}{41} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right) \\
&\sim \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & 0 & \color{red}1 & \frac{15}{41} \\ 0 & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & \frac{8}{41} \\ 0 & 0 & \color{red}0 & 0 \end{array}\right)
\end{align*}
Note that, as we always expect from the normal equation, we have consistency; there is no zero row with a non-zero augmented number. That is, we have a solution. Since $A^\top A$ is not invertible, we have a column without a pivot, which gives us a free variable. Since it occurs in the third column, $x_3$ is a good candidate to assign as a free variable.

Let $t = x_3$. We have from the first row, $x_1 + x_3 = \frac{15}{41}$, so $x_1 = -t + \frac{15}{41}$. From the second row, $x_2 - x_3 = \frac{8}{41}$, so $x_2 = t + \frac{8}{41}$.

Now, the actual point $\vec{y}$ that is closest to $\vec{t}$ from the columnspace of $A$ is given by $A \vec{x}$, where $\vec{x}$ is one of the above solution. It doesn't matter which; just pick any value of $t$ you want ($t = 0$ is usually easy). However, I'm going to leave $t$ arbitrary just to demonstrate how it doesn't matter. We have
\begin{align*}
\vec{y} &= A \vec{x} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 2 & -1 & 3 \\ -1 & 1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -t + \frac{15}{41} \\ t + \frac{8}{41} \\ t \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} 1(-t + \frac{15}{41}) + 2(t + \frac{8}{41}) - 1t \\ 0(-t + \frac{15}{41}) + -1(t + \frac{8}{41}) + 1t \\ 2(-t + \frac{15}{41}) - 1(t + \frac{8}{41}) + 3t \\ -1(-t + \frac{15}{41}) + 1(t + \frac{8}{41}) - 2t \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} \frac{31}{41} \\ -\frac{8}{41} \\ \frac{22}{41} \\ -\frac{7}{41} \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
That is, the result of the least squares doesn't depend on $t$, i.e. it doesn't depend on your choice of vector from the normal equation. Solving via Gauss-Jordan elimination, then arbitrarily picking a solution, will obtain you to the same unique minimiser for the least squares problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is always square.

Consider $A $ be a $ m\times n$ matrix.  The dimensions of $A^T $ will be $ n \times m$

Hence $A^TA$ will have dimensions $ n \times n$ which is clearly a square matrix.

However in some cases when $A=0$ we cannot find a inverse.

Answer (score 0):

It's always square.If $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ then $A^{T} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ so $A^{T}A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$

The inverse will only exist if $A$ is full rank since $\textrm{Rank}(A) = \textrm{Rank}(A^{T}A)$

However the minimum norm solution to $\|Ax - b\|^{2}$ is given by the solution to $A^{T}Ax = A^{T}b$ which is called the normal equations. Not a good method of solving it directly though since $\kappa(A^{T}A) = \kappa(A)^{2}$